# Alternative to System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection class in .Net standard 2.0

Tags: .net, .net-standard, sqlconnection

I am converting a .Net core 2.1 project to .Net standard project. In .Net core 2.1 project, there was a Nuget package : System.Data.SqlClient (Contains class SqlConnection). This Nuget package and so class SqlConnection is not available in .Net Standard.

Is there any alternative to use SqlConnection in .Net standard?

Answer (score 4):

> This Nuget package and so class SqlConnection is not available in .Net Standard

Yes, it is; expand Dependencies [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient), and you should see that it includes targets for .NET Standard 1.2, .NET Standard 1.3, and .NET Standard 2.0; in your case, the latter should be selected automatically.

There is also the related-but-different Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package, [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient), which has targets for .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Standard 2.1

That said: honestly, you're probably better off avoiding .NET Standard at this point, and just move to a recent .NET Core (or later) version, ideally .NET 5.

Comment: I cant see option to add it through nuget. the package link says that it supports .net standard 2.0 but it does not show in nuget.

Comment: @saadbinsami what tool are you using here? It should work just fine. The main exception would be things like "Unity". Is this Unity?

Comment: I was using Nuget

Comment: @saad I meant as your target platform; it is absolutely available on nuget - I've shown the links, they work just fine as package refs for most conventional targets

Comment: yes package was available on my target plateform.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a version for System.Data.SqlClient

Maybe you need to try work with Entity Framework to get the reference or in any case you can work with ADO.NET but there is a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I installed System.Data.Client through command line. It surprisingly installed. May be there was some issue with nuget.

Comment: Editing the csproj is usually the easiest way to add package references; nuget includes the XML for this on one of the tabs